# Automatically run 'make check' if 'make install' is executed in autotools

Tags: c++, autotools

Is it possible to execute 'make check' prior to 'make install' and abort the install if check failed?

The behavior should be like this:

1. User runs 'make install'
2. 'make check' is run.
3. If check failed install is not executed. Otherwise install is executed.

edit:

I got it working by overriding the install rule in the top level Makefile.am like this:

```
install: check install-recursive
```

But I would rather have a solution that does not override the install target.

Comment: It is possible, but why would you want to do that?  If the user wants a fast install, or does not want to run the test suite for any reason, you should allow the user to make that choice.  If you want to put a hook on the check target that writes a stamp file, and then emit a warning during 'make install' to indicate that the test suite has not been run, that is fine, but you should not take the choice away from the user.

Comment: @WilliamPursell, I strongly agree. The user is unable to install if a "corner case" test should fail or if a test of a feature that the user cares nothing about should fail.  I've even had `make check`s that fail just because of minor differences of how tools like `sed` arrange the (correct) test output on different flavors of Unix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can hook into the install process using the `install-exec-local` or `install-data-local` targets:

```
install-exec-local: check
```

Comment: If I use exec-local the tests are run somewhere in the middle of the install process.

Comment: Then the only way is to override the install target.